# static method on LinqSql partial classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have several Linq-2-sql classes generated by visual studio and now I am adding some functionality on the class level. Like I have an Orders class and I have static methods like 'getAllOrdersBetween(date_from,date_end)'. So i can call: tb_orders.getAll...

Is that the right place to put this kind of functionality? And does it harm performance to have these kind of static methods on the Linq-2-sql entity class?

Thanks for your advice,
Pleun

Comment: Can you show some code example of how you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. You should do some searches here for 'Repository' and 'Repository pattern.' what you're describing is an object that knows how to find orders given specific criteria. You will want to seperate this from your orders class so you can test it independently and substitute different kinds of repositories. You don't want your orders to 'know' they come from linq2sql.

Comment: ok, I will do so. And can you comment on the performance aspect. Does it harm to have these 'extra' static methods or does the compiler handle that efficiently?

Comment: I don't think the problem will be performance nearly as much as decoupling and testing.